# R How to replace NAs in the upper triangle of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, na

I'm guessing it's a combination of the is.na function and upper.tri function but I couldn't figure it out

Say I have a matrix like this:

```
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1   NA   NA   3
# [2,]    NA  1    NA   NA
# [3,]    NA  NA    1   NA
# [4,]    NA  NA   NA   NA
```

I want to replace NAs in the upper half to be 0 and keep the lower half I.e,

```
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1   0     0   3
# [2,]    NA  1     0   0
# [3,]    NA  NA    1   0
# [4,]    NA  NA   NA   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or

```
 m <- structure(c(1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, 3, NA, 
  NA, NA), .Dim = c(4L, 4L))

 m[upper.tri(m, diag=T) & is.na(m)] <- 0
  m
 #     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 #[1,]    1    0    0    3
 #[2,]   NA    1    0    0
 #[3,]   NA   NA    1    0
 #[4,]   NA   NA   NA    0
```